# iText image alignment on second page

Tags: android, image, pdf, itext

I am creating a PDF document with images and text in Android using iText. Each page has an image at the top followed by some text. On the first page the image is correctly aligned to the top margin of the page, but on subsequent pages there is a gap of approximately 10 points between the top margin and the top of the image.

Here's my code:

```
// Create PDF document object
float pageMargin = 72;
document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document(PageSize.A4, pageMargin, pageMargin, pageMargin, pageMargin);
PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(myFile.getAbsoluteFile()));
document.open();
PdfContentByte cb = pdfWriter.getDirectContent();

for (PicturePage picPage : picPageList)
{
    // Draw a border on the page
    cb.moveTo(pageMargin, pageMargin);
    cb.lineTo(pageMargin, (pageHeight - pageMargin));
    cb.lineTo((pageWidth - pageMargin), (pageHeight - pageMargin));
    cb.lineTo((pageWidth - pageMargin), pageMargin);
    cb.lineTo(pageMargin, pageMargin);
    cb.stroke();

    // Get an image from the file system and scale to required size
    String imgFileName = picPage.getImagePath();
    image = Image.getInstance(imgFileName);
    float fitWidth = 400;
    float fitHeight = 300;
    image.scaleToFit(fitWidth, fitHeight);

    image.setAlignment(Image.ALIGN_CENTER | Image.ALIGN_TOP);
    document.add(image);

    // Add the text to the page.
    String theText = picPage.getText();
    String[] arrParagraphs = theText.split("\n");

    for (int i=0; i<arrParagraphs.length; i++)
    {
        String paragraphText = arrParagraphs[i];
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph(paragraphText);
        document.add(p);
    }

    // Start a new page
    document.newPage();
}
```

I have tried various combinations of Image.ALIGN... and Image.TEXTWRAP but none of them remove the gap. I tried changing the order of placing the image and the border but no change. I have also tried removing the text and the border but the placement of the image is still the same.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks,
Declan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you won't mind if I share my opinion, but I don't like your code. There are much better ways to render images followed by a caption than the way you do it.

Now let me explain what causes the small gap to appear.

When you first create your document, the value of the *leading* is zero. (The *leading* is the distance between the baselines of two consecutive lines). This value changes as soon as you add the first object that defines a leading. In your case, this object is a `Paragraph`.

Although you do not define a leading explicitly, your paragraph uses a default font (Helvetica) and a default font size (12). The default leading is 1.5 times the font size (18).

Now when you go to the next page, that leading is used, introducing a small gap preceding the image. You could solve this by adding an empty `Paragraph` with leading 0 before triggering a new page:

```
document.add(new Paragraph(0));
```

(Add this before `document.newPage();`.)

However: if I were you, I'd throw away my code, and I'd add my image and my caption using a `PdfPTable` with a fixed width and fixed heights for the cells. You can add this table either using `document.add()`, or using the `writeSelectedRows()` method. Alternatively I could add the image at an absolute position and add the caption using a `ColumnText` object. There are many different ways to achieve what you want. The way you do it may work, but it's not optimal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Bruno. I've only been using iText for a couple of days so I'm still figuring out all the concepts. I'll try out your suggestions for alternatives also. Thanks again.